# Unable to create login integration with PHPBB3

Tags: php, phpbb

I want to integrate a login script with PHPBB3.

I have [this](http://pastebin.com/z5iBE3hZ) code written.

It works well if I comment this line.

```
require 'forum/includes/functions.php';
```

But shows no output if this line is executed.

Comment: Well there must be some error in that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried commenting

```
if (!defined('IN_PHPBB'))
{
    exit;
}
```

from

```
require 'forum/includes/functions.php';
```

Or write this line before your include.

```
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
```